# Displaying Maximum and Minimum Values in C

Tags: c

I'm having a problem with displaying the lowest average. I've made a terminating value of to end the exam score input. When I trigger -999 and display the lowest exam score I receive the value of -999 instead of the actual lowest score. How do I exclude this value?

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int menuChoice, scoreCount = 0;
    float examScore = 0.0, 
          maxScore = 0.0,
          minScore = 0.0, 
          avgScore = 0.0, 
          sumScore = 0.0;

    printf("************************************\n");
    printf("1-> Enter an Exam Score\n");
    printf("2-> Display the highest exam score\n");
    printf("3-> Display the lowest exam score\n");
    printf("4-> Display the average exam score\n");
    printf("5-> Quit the program\n");
    printf("************************************\n\n");

    printf("Select a number that corresponds to the menu :\n");
    scanf("%d", &menuChoice);

    while(menuChoice != 5) 
    {
        switch(menuChoice)
        {
        case 1:
            while(examScore != -999)
            {
                printf("Enter an exam score (enter -999 to quit score input):\n");
                scanf("%f", &examScore);
                printf("The score you've entered equates to : %.2f\n\n", examScore);
                scoreCount++;

                if(maxScore < examScore)
                {
                    maxScore = examScore;
                }
                if(minScore > examScore)
                {
                    minScore = examScore;
                }
                else if(examScore < 0 || examScore > 100)
                {
                  printf("Exam Scores range from 0.0 - 100.0\n");
                }
                sumScore += examScore;
                avgScore = sumScore / scoreCount;
            }
            break;

        case 2:
            printf("The highest exam score is : %.2f\n", maxScore);
            break;

        case 3:
            printf("The lowest exam score is : %.2f\n", minScore);
            break;

        case 4:
            printf("The average exam score is : %.2f", avgScore);              
            break;

        default:
            printf("You've entered an invalid menu choice, review more carefully!");
            break;
        }

        printf("Select a number that corresponds to the menu :\n");
        scanf("%d", &menuChoice);
    } 

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Get rid of the [system("pause");](http://www.gidnetwork.com/b-61.html)! I almost ran this on my machine, and the `pause` command on my machine pauses the cooling system for my home nuclear reactor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like everyone else said you do your check for `-999` after you process that score. Also I assume you should only update the `minScore` whenever the current exam is lower so you should have something like:

```
if(maxScore < examScore)
{
    maxScore = examScore;
}

if(minScore > examScore)
{
   minScore = examScore;
}
```

Finally you should initialize all your variables before using them.

EDIT:

```
while(...) 
   printf("Enter an exam score (enter -999 to quit score input):\n");
   scanf("%f", &examScore);
   printf("The score you've entered equates to : %.2f\n\n", examScore);

   if(examScore < 0 || examScore > 100)
   {
       printf("Exam Scores range from 0.0 - 100.0\n");
       continue; //goes back to the top of the loop skipping everything else
   } 
   //At this point you know the score is valid so you can process it
   scoreCount++;

   if(maxScore < examScore)
   {
       maxScore = examScore;
   }
   if(minScore > examScore)
   {
      minScore = examScore;
   }
   sumScore += examScore;
   avgScore = sumScore / scoreCount;
}
```

If it's not in a loop or you don't want to use `continue` you can simply put everything else (all the processing stuff) in an `else` block after the validity check.

Comment: That else does not belong there ... the first score is both the min and the max.

Comment: @JimBalter That's true. I tried to think of a case where it would have to execute both but I missed the obvious one. Fixed.

Comment: I've been writing code for over 40 years and have encountered this bug or one like it nearly that many times. Note that, by trying to think of a case where the else would fail, you not only introduced a bug, but you expended unnecessary effort by trying to think of such a case, and you committed the sin of premature optimization ... which likely would backfire; in modern machines, the extra branch can cause the code to run slower. Even if the else would work, it should be avoided.

Comment: I'm still working on fixing that terminating value. I've made some edits and solved for the average and made an error detection for the examScore input.

Comment: Check the valid range first (along with `-999` for a terminating) then if the range isn't valid skip the rest of the loop (`continue` will accomplish that).

Comment: @twain249 I took out the while loop that included the terminating value. I like the functionality of just handling one score and then being able to another score if needed. The highest exam score is being calculated along with the correct score count & average, but the lowest value is being displayed at 0. What's causing this?

Comment: @user1424811 You are initializing the `minScore` to `0` which would be lower than any other score. You should initialize it to something bigger than any valid score like `101` or if you want to include `float.h` you can use `FLT_MAX`.

Comment: @twain249 I see... I just tried including float.h as well as FLT_MAX and it worked to spec! I'm going to look into that library so I can have a better understanding as to how it works so I'll know when to use it for future reference. One last thing... I wrote an error detection included in the else if block and if the user enters a value over 100 it would've counted that as the max score entered rather than just an invalid entry. How can I go about solving for a way to exclude that value?

Comment: The problem is you are checking that after processing the values. I'll edit my answer to show you how to rearrange it.

Comment: @twain249 I needed to understand this the most. Precedence is something I should've been aware of from the beginning. I appreciate the feedback and Thank you for showing me this.

Comment: You've left out the test for -999; your code will just ignore it and continue. And `while(...)` should be `while(1)` ... there's nothing to test for at that point. (This is what Djikstra called "loop and a half".)

Answer (score 1):

Fix the logic of your while loop.  You update `minScore` before checking to see whether `examScore` is -999, so that's not good.

Also you should initialize variables like `examScore` before using them, and you should NOT do exact comparisons like `examScore != -999` with floats.  Either change to ints or do a more forgiving comparison like `examScore < -998`.

Comment: `examScore` is also used before being initialized.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following program.  Will `do_stuff` be called?

```
int foo;
while (foo != 5) {
   foo = 5;
   do_stuff();
}
```

Actually the behavior is undefined because `foo` is tested before it's initialized.  Your code has the same problem, with `examScore`.  Since this is homework, this is just a hint - how would you fix the simple program above?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with that code is that when the user enters -999 it processes that as a test score. The loop needs to be restructured so that it breaks immediately after user input.

Answer (score 0):

There's a logical error besides the values without `init` and compare tow float directly problems.
In your case 1 while loop, you need determine if the user input meet the terminate condition first, then to process it. Also the `minScore` need a comparison before assignment, just like what twain249 said.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int scoreCount = 0;
    float maxScore = -1000.0,
          minScore = 1000.0,
          sumScore = 0.0;

    printf("************************************\n");
    printf("1-> Enter Exam Scores\n");
    printf("2-> Display the highest exam score\n");
    printf("3-> Display the lowest exam score\n");
    printf("4-> Display the average exam score\n");
    printf("5-> Quit the program\n");
    printf("************************************\n\n");

    for(;;)
    {
        int menuChoice;
        printf("Select a number that corresponds to the menu:\n");
        scanf("%d", &menuChoice);

        if(scoreCount == 0 && menuChoice >= 2 && menuChoice <= 4)
        {
            printf("Please enter some scores by choosing menu item 1\n");
            continue;
        }

        switch(menuChoice)
        {
        case 1:
            for(;;)
            {
                float examScore;
                printf("Enter an exam score (enter -999 to quit score input):\n");
                scanf("%f", &examScore);
                if (examScore == -999)
                    break;
                printf("The score you've entered equates to : %.2f\n\n", examScore);
                if(examScore < 0 || examScore > 100)
                {
                    printf("Exam scores range from 0.0 - 100.0\n");
                    continue;
                }

                sumScore += examScore;
                ++scoreCount;

                if(maxScore < examScore)
                {
                    maxScore = examScore;
                }
                if(minScore > examScore)
                {
                    minScore = examScore;
                }
            }
            break;

        case 2:
            printf("The highest exam score is : %.2f\n", maxScore);
            break;

        case 3:
            printf("The lowest exam score is : %.2f\n", minScore);
            break;

        case 4:
        {
            float avgScore = sumScore / scoreCount;
            printf("The average exam score is : %.2f\n", avgScore);
            break;
        }

        default:
            printf("You've entered an invalid menu choice, review more carefully!");
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems: negative scores are stored as minimums but when fixed then init value of min score would be 0 so you could not be able to get higher values.
Initialize min score to 100 if input of min-check does not exceed 100 (initA in code comment) OR init with first value (based on score count - initB).
Entering exam scores could be also quit by simply providing value out of range:

```
float minScore = 100.0; /* initA */
/* .. */
    case 1 :
    {
        printf("Enter an exam score (0..100): "); scanf("%f", &examScore);
        while( ( 0.0 <= examScore ) && ( examScore <= 100.0 ) )
        {
            if( 0 == scoreCount ) { minScore = examScore; } /* initB */
            ++scoreCount;
            if( maxScore < examScore ) { maxScore = examScore; }
            if( minScore < examScore ) { minScore = examScore; }
            sumScore += examScore;
            avgScore = sumScore / scoreCount;
            printf("Enter an exam score (0..100): "); scanf("%f", &examScore);
        }
        break;
    }
```

Not all of your printf are closed with `\n`.